# Using PHP to rename files with spaces

Tags: php, rename, filenames, spaces

I've got files with spaces in their names that are already on my server. I want to rename them with underscores. I've tried putting a slash before the space, and I've tried replacing the space with %20. Still PHP gives me:

> No such file or directory.

Here's my code:

```
$dir = './';
$dhandle = opendir($dir);
$old_files = array();

if ($dhandle) {
    while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dhandle)))
    {
        if ( ($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') )
        {
            $old_files[] = (is_dir( "./$fname" )) ? "(Dir) {$fname}" : $fname;
        }
    }
    closedir($dhandle);
}

$new_files = str_replace(' ', '_', $old_files);
$x = 0;
foreach($old_files as $file)
{
    rename(rawurlencode($file), $new_files[$x++]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the no such file error does not happen if you don't attempt the rename?  A good first step when debugging is to simplify the problem until it's no longer buggy.

I can't tell if you did this because it wasn't working at first or not, but you definitely should not be using `rawurlencode()` on a local filename, that's guaranteed to screw things up.  Additionally, I'm curious what you're doing with `"(Dir) {$fname}"` - that seems to also be a bug.  I suspect more likely what you want to do is:

```
if ( ($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') && !is_dir("./$fname" )) 
{
  $old_files[] = $fname;
}
```

You should also realize, however, that what `dir` returns is the filename *relative to the directory passed* so you need to make sure your `is_dir()` and rename operations take that into account.  So more than likely you want to say:

```
is_dir($dir.'/'.$fname);
```

and

```
rename($dir.'/'.$file,$dir.'/'.$new_files[$x++]);
```

Comment: I needed the $dir.'/'. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a:

```
print "$file\n";
```

before the rename statement to see what you're getting.

Also, you should add a strstr($fname, ' ') to your if statement before adding the file to the array so you only operate on filenames containing a space:

```
if ( ($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') && !is_dir("./$fname" ) && strstr($fname, ' ')) 
{
  $old_files[] = $fname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to generate a quick hack to clean up some really badly named files. Here's my code; use it if you want.

```
<?php
    $dir = './';
    $dhandle = opendir($dir);
    $old_files = array();

    if ($dhandle) {
    while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dhandle))) {
        if ( ($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') && !is_dir("./$fname" ))
             $old_files[] = $fname;
       }
       closedir($dhandle);
    }

    foreach($old_files as $file)
    {
        $new_name = str_replace(',', '', str_replace('&', '', str_replace(' ','',$file)));
        rename("./".$file, "./".$new_name);
        echo $new_name."\n";
    }
```